# Rich ACLs with Azure Storage - delegating to AD?

Tags: azure, azure-storage

How do I build a rich storage ACL policy system with Azure storage?

I want to have a blob container that has the following users:

- public - read-only against some set of blobs
- Uploader - read-write against some subset of blob names, these keys are shared out to semi-trusted build machines
- shared admin - full capabilities against this blob subset

Ideally these users are accounts driven through Azure AD, so I can use the full directory service power with them... :)

My understanding of shared access keys is that they are (1) time-limited and (2) have to be created with hand-tooled code. My desire is that I can do something similar to AWS IAM policies on S3... :-)

Comment: Will it be OK for you to use 3rd party tools for this purpose?

Comment: @GauravMantri - depends on the complexity and cost. I am building this infrastructure on my own for future professional use.

Answer (score 3):

Thing like `AWS IAM Policies for S3` does not exist for Azure Blob Storage today. Azure recently started a `Role Based Access Control (RBAC)` and is available for Azure Storage but it is limited to performing management activities only like creating storage accounts etc. It is yet not available for perform data management activities like uploading blobs etc.

You may want to look at [`Azure Rights Management Service (Azure RMS)`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-in/library/jj585026.aspx) and see if it is a right solution for your needs. If you search for `Azure RMS Blob` you will find one of the search results link to a PDF file which talks about securing blob storage with this service (the link directly downloads the PDF file and hence I could not include it here).

If you're looking for a 3rd party service to do this, do take a look at the [`"Team Edition" of Cloud Portam`](http://cloudportam.com/features/team-edition) (a service I am building currently). We recently released the Team Edition. In short, Cloud Portam is a browser-based Azure Explorer and it supports managing Azure Storage, Search Service and DocumentDB accounts. The Team Edition makes use of your Azure AD for user authentication and you can grant permissions (None, Read-Only, Read-Write and Read-Write-Delete) on the Azure resources you manage through this application.

Comment: Interesting. That is disappointing, I had thought Azure was more mature.  Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

Paul,

While Gaurav is correct in that Azure Storage does not have AD integration today, I wanted to point out a couple of things about shared access signatures from your post:

> My understanding of shared access keys is that they are (1) time-limited and (2) have to be created with hand-tooled code

1) A sas token/uri does not need to have an expiry date on it (it's an optional field), so in that sense they are not time-limited and need not be regenerated unless you change the shared key with which you generated the token
2) You can use PS cmdlets to do this for e.g.: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn806416.aspx. Some storage explorers also support creation of sas tokens/uris statically without you having to write code for it.

Comment: Thanks for your response! It's nice to have an authoritative response. Followup question: are there tools usable on Linux/OSX to generate these urls?  (I can write one myself, but it is nice when there are prebaked tools for the purpose).  Finally, I really hope that AD integration is on the roadmap for Azure Storage.